# if (expression) VS "Traditional If" in AHK

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

The following simple script displays Yes, then No.

I don't get it.

From what I read in the AHK documentation, I suspect this has something to do with the if (expression) VS "Traditional If".
But I find the documentation not very clear on this subject.

Could someone explain this?

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv

Toto := "c"

If (Toto In a,b)
    MsgBox Yes
Else
    MsgBox No

If Toto In a,b
    MsgBox Yes
Else
    MsgBox No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `IN` with expressions.

Your first example uses an expression, which does not support the use of `IN`.  Therefore the behavior of the statement is undefined.

Your second example is correct and produces a correct result.

From https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm:

> The operators "between", "is", "in", and "contains" are not supported
>   in expressions.